# ScriptManager required even though it is present

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ajax

i am getting following error when i am running AJAX enabled ASP.Net application

The control with ID 'FilteredTextBoxExtender1' requires a ScriptManager on the page. The ScriptManager must appear before any controls that need it.

even though i have ScriptManager in my page

what wrong i am doing please give suggestions

thanks in advance

```
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:scriptmanager id="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
    <div>
        <cc1:filteredtextboxextender id="FilteredTextBoxExtender1" targetcontrolid="textbox1"
            filtertype="Numbers" runat="server">  </cc1:filteredtextboxextender>
        <asp:textbox id="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:textbox>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

What version of the toolkit? With recent versions at the time of writing, you need to use `toolkitscriptmanager` instead of the "normal" `scriptmanager`.

Comment: thanks y34h its working fine when i replaced my scriptmanager with toolkitscriptmanager thanks alot

Comment: @user271628 How about accepting the answer since its correct?

Answer (score 0):

Place ScriptManager right before UpdatePanel